# Restrict User to Close Story unless all child tasks are closed

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible if we can restrict people to move the user story to closed state unless all associated tasks (child task) are moved to closed state.

Answer (score 1):

At of this time, it is not supported to restrict user to close work items unless all child task are closed. There is already a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/do-not-close-a-user-story-unless-all-tasks-are-clo-1/802993) in Developer Community. You can vote or comment on it.

Here are some workaround:

1. You can write some script to implement this issue by client API. You can refer to [this blog](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/automation-of-state-changing-for-azure-devops-work-items-based-on-states-of-child-work-items/) for detailed information.
2. You can use Azure Function to implement this. Please refer to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli). It also need some  customed code.